# Best camera for me

Tags: camera-recommendation

I need to buy a camera. I have never used a DSLR before but I am a fast learner. I don't know which one I should get since there are too many options out there. I thought it would be best if I had the advice of someone with experience.

Basically, I am looking for a good quality camera that would take great pics regardless of the lighting. I recently moved to a gorgeous country and I want to take pictures of everything. I have always been into photography. I really like the idea of getting a Canon or a Nikon, but would consider other good ones as well. I want one that has wifi and that is not extremely bulky. It would be better if it was touch screen enabled. And finally, my budget is €600 including a lens. Please advise on what you think would be best for me.

Comment: We can explain features or help you understand differences between cameras, but nobody here can tell you what's right for you. We don't know you. Also, purchasing advice questions are decided off topic here because they're generally helpful only to one person, they become outdated very quickly, and they're usually pretty subjective. For those reasons, I expect this question will be put on hold very quickly. Don't take it personally -- that's just how this site works. Consider editing your question to ask about specific information you need to make an informed decision.

Comment: Here's a helpful explanation from the [tag:camera-recommendation] tag wiki: *Good camera recommendation questions deal with what cameras are appropriate for a specific task or meet special requirements. This tag should not be used for shopping questions. Asking for comparisons between two cameras should be avoided unless motivated by clear situational detail.*

Comment: Possibly see: [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first “serious” camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987), [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876) and [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746). I will say, your budget seems awfully low to me. Double it, and dSLR is more of a viable option.

Comment: @inkista, you are recommending to start directly with a pro DSLR because it will (maybe) be cheaper in the long run? I think entry kit DSLR such as the 700D or the D5200 are good starters.

Comment: @Olivier, no. I'm recommending doing more reading and research. :) But also that 600 euros can get you a camera body+kit. But not a camera body+3 lenses, a flash, tripod and bag. Budget for the system, not just the body. An enthusiast compact may be a better fit for that budget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Answer (score 2):

**The camera you want doesn't exist as no camera takes** "***great pics regardless of the lighting***".

Sure, a DSLR seems like a good place to start when one want to get into *serious* photography, but almost any cellphone can take great pictures if the conditions are right.

Have a look at the following questions/answers :

- [Is buying a camera and trying things yourself the best way to learn?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/is-buying-a-camera-and-trying-things-yourself-the-best-way-to-learn)
- [Should I buy a DSLR to get started?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/417/should-i-buy-a-dslr-to-get-started)
- [How to start the basics of photography, which is the best entry level SLR camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/how-to-start-the-basics-of-photography-which-is-the-best-entry-level-slr-camera)
- [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first "serious" camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/what-do-i-need-to-consider-to-choose-between-dslr-mirrorless-or-a-compact-as-m)
- [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)
- [Getting the right DSLR from the very beginning](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/31037/getting-the-right-dslr-from-the-very-beginning)
- [Are there disadvantages to a prosumer camera for a beginner, aside from cost?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/are-there-disadvantages-to-a-prosumer-camera-for-a-beginner-aside-from-cost)